# Вывод изображения из дополненной модели User

Tags: python, django

Я дополнил модель `User` привязав к ней `ImageField` через onetoone

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', verbose_name='Изображение')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'
```

Как вывести эту картинку в шаблоне?

Comment: Как пытались? С чем конкретно возникла проблема? У вас много картинок на одного пользователя? Или много пользователей на одну картинку? Код покажите.

Comment: Одна картинка на одного пользователя, аватар его так сказать. from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/users', verbose_name='Изображение')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Профиль'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Профили'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="{{ user.userprofile.avatar.url }}">
```